# Can't Install Azure IoT Edge RC4 on redhat

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Error: Package: aziot-edge-1.2.0-0.1.rc4.el7.x86_64 (/aziot-edge-1.2.0-0.1.rc4.el7.x86_64)
Requires: aziot-identity-service >= 1.2.0-0.1.rc4
Installed: aziot-identity-service-1.2.0~rc4-1.x86_64 (@/aziot-identity-service-1.2.0.rc4-1.x86_64)
aziot-identity-service = 1.2.0~rc4-1

Comment: Re-download the aziot-edge rpm and try again.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The iotedge team recently made a change to fix this problem. If you remove the packages and try again I think it should work.

Comment: Qusp if this worked can you verify the answer?